# Grabbing certain data from sorted list in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I'm running analysis on a set of data and returning a list of summary statistics for each comparison. My program prints out both a summary of the results and a file which contains all of the results. For the summary I want only a LIMITED number of significant results. So I loop through my results and create a list of lists of ALL significant results:

```
for variable in self.output:
    if self.output_p[variable] <= self.sig_level:
        summary_results.append(MY_LIST)
```

I then sort this list, first by a variable name pair `(X,Y)`, alphabetical order, and then by descending effect size:

```
summary_results.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0].lower(), x[1].lower(), -x[3]), reverse=False)
```

This pair `(X,Y)` shows up between 0 and 2000 times, depending on some other variable Z. I want to then print the first 10 instances of each `(X,Y)` pair (if `(X,Y)` appears less then 10 times then print all instances).

My thought was to loop through `summary_results` and keep track of the current and last `(X,Y)`, counting the number of times it appears, not printing when count > 10.

Is there an easier, more Pythonic way?

Comment: Your sort function doesn't seem to refer to Y at all.  Is (X,Y) a tuple, or is it a string?  And what do you want to print in the summary?  Just the (X,Y) pair itself, or some values along with it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing notation, (X,Y) = (x[0],x[1])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My thought was to loop through summary_results ... counting the number of times it appears, not printing when count > 10.

Yeah, that's the way I'd do it too. You can use `itertools.groupby` to avoid manually tracking the pairs yourself.

```
import itertools
def truncate_groups(seq, max_group_size, key):
    """yield only the first `max_group_size` elements from each sub-group of `seq`"""
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(seq, key):
        for item in list(group)[:max_group_size]:
            yield item

for row in truncate_groups(summary_results, 10, lambda x: x[0].lower(), x[1].lower()):
    print row
```